# How to get first and last items number with Zend Paginator?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I need to get the fisrt item and last item number in my view.phtml.

The trouble is that I can't acces this properties in my pagination control, because of the structure of the html. For example:

```
<div class="list">
.... rows ...
<div class="items"> 1 - 18 of 540</div>
</div>
<div id="pagination">
<?php echo $this->paginator; ?>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to access to those properties from the view? I just can't figure out how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->paginator->first;
$this->paginator->last;
```

Answer (score 2):

First item will be 1 and last item count would be `$paginator->getTotalItemCount();`

Answer (score 1):

There is [example code in the Zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html), where first and last page links are generated.